# Parsing twilio transcription GET request within studio flow?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-studio

EDIT: My question is similar to [Twilio - Studio - HTTP Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72090293/twilio-studio-http-request) except that the response I get is in xml rather than JSON. So is there a way i can specify a particular xml tag using liquid?

I have designed a studio flow which is as follows

1. On Incoming call:
2. Plays message telling caller to leave a voicemail
3. Records voicemail
4. Upon hangup, retrieves the transcription of the voicemail using the 'Make HTTP Request' widget using "GET https://user:pass@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Recordings/{RecordingSid}/Transcriptions/ "
5. Sends that response to a phone number via SMS by putting "{{widget.http_request.body}}" in the message box of the "send_message" widget.

Now I'm so close to that goal however I am having trouble on step 4. I need the response to be turned into just the  tag within the xml response. Instead I get the entirety of it which looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<TwilioResponse>
    <Transcriptions end="0" firstpageuri="/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC8275ec8e6fb8c37d6b2a5eca99f0dae6/Recordings/RE1595c7b8bc2b8850401ba44fba0dd24d/Transcriptions?PageSize=50&amp;Page=0" nextpageuri="" page="0" pagesize="50" previouspageuri="" start="0" uri="/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC8275ec8e6fb8c37d6b2a5eca99f0dae6/Recordings/RE1595c7b8bc2b8850401ba44fba0dd24d/Transcriptions?PageSize=50&amp;Page=0">
        <Transcription>
            <Sid>TRbcdfd8fb2fe226ed741b14a05a46cfef</Sid>
            <DateCreated>Wed, 17 Aug 2022 19:27:18 +0000</DateCreated>
            <DateUpdated>Wed, 17 Aug 2022 19:27:42 +0000</DateUpdated> 
            <AccountSid>AC8275ec8e6fb8c37d6b2a5eca99f0dae6</AccountSid> 
            <Status>completed</Status><Type>fast</Type> 
            <RecordingSid>RE1595c7b8bc2b8850401ba44fba0dd24d</RecordingSid> 
            <Duration>7</Duration>
            <TranscriptionText>Hello. Hello, Hello, Hello, Hello. Hello.</TranscriptionText>
            <ApiVersion>2010-04-01</ApiVersion>
            <Price/>
            <PriceUnit>USD</PriceUnit>
            <Uri>/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC8275ec8e6fb8c37d6b2a5eca99f0dae6/Transcriptions/TRbcdfd8fb2fe226ed741b14a05a46cfef</Uri>
        </Transcription>
    </Transcriptions>
</TwilioResponse>
```

As you can see, I only need the content between the "TranscriptionText" tags, but currently my HTTP_Request widget returns all of the above. How can I do this within studio? I am trying to keep everything contained in Twilio so any solutions involving outside servers are not desired.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding .json to the end, like below, to get a JSON response Studio can parse.

```
/2010-04-01/Accounts/{YourAccountSid}/Recordings/{RecordingSid}/Transcriptions.json
```

Comment: thank you. I solved my problem by adding the .json and then retrieve only the text portion using {{widgets.get_transcript.parsed.transcriptions[0].transcription_text}}. I cannot believe how long I was stuck on this and all I needed was ".json"....smh.